# How to use enum in Angular 2 templates

Tags: angular

I am trying to use enum in angularjs 2 templates.
Below is my code

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="{{activeSection == SectionType.Primary ? 'active': ''}}"><a href="javscript:void(0);" (click)="setActiveSection(SectionType.Primary)">Primary Details</a></li>
    <li class="{{activeSection == SectionType.Aditional ? 'active': ''}}"><a href="javscript:void(0);" (click)="setActiveSection(SectionType.Aditional)">Additional Details</a></li>
    <li class="{{activeSection == SectionType.Payment ? 'active': ''}}"><a href="javscript:void(0);" (click)="setActiveSection(SectionType.Payment)">Payment Settings </a></li>           
  </ul>`
  })
  export class TestComponent{
  activeSection: SectionType = SectionType.Primary;
   setActiveSection(section: SectionType) {
        this.activeSection = section;
    }
}
```

here is my enum:

```
enum SectionType {
    Primary,
    Aditional,
    Payment
}
```

It is throwing EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Primary' of undefined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SectionType can't be used directly within the template. Either you set it to a property of your component, either you add specify methods to check:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="{{isPrimarySection(activeSection) ? 'active': ''}}"><a href="javscript:void(0);" (click)="setActiveSection(SectionType.Primary)">Primary Details</a></li>
        (...)
      </ul>
    `
  })
  export class TestComponent{
    activeSection: SectionType = SectionType.Primary;
    setActiveSection(section: SectionType) {
      this.activeSection = section;
    }
    isPrimarySection(activeSection) {
      return activeSection == SectionType.Primary
    }
 }
```

or

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="{{activeSection == SectionType.Primary ? 'active': ''}}"><a href="javscript:void(0);" (click)="setActiveSection(SectionType.Primary)">Primary Details</a></li>
      (...)
    </ul>`
  })
  export class TestComponent{
    activeSection: SectionType = SectionType.Primary;
    setActiveSection(section: SectionType) {
      this.activeSection = section;
    }
    SectionType:SectionType = SectionType;
  }
```

Comment: First solution may work but what about `(click)="setActiveSection(SectionType.Primary)"`
and second solution 
`SectionType: SectionType = SectionType;` is giving error
Type 'typeof SectionType' is not assignable to type 'SectionType'

Comment: Try this rather: `SectionType = SectionType;`

Comment: I works with `SectionType:any = SectionType;`. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mos2zocjWxiYx5rnY4PI?p=preview.

Comment: The line `SectionType:SectionType = SectionType` is wrong because `SectionType` is not of type `SectionType`, it's actually an `enum`. In Java it would be something like `SectionType: Enum< SectionType>` but I guess in TypeScript you can't do that. I suspect that this is a limitation, since you cannot use enum types correctly from a template (I mean the type itself, not the values). :/

Comment: `SectionType: typeof SectionType = SectionType;` also works.

Answer (score 40):

The simple way to use an Enum in a template is

```ts
@Component(...)
export class MyComp {
  public MyEnum: any = MyEnum;
}
```

Then in template:

```html
<select>
  <option value="MyEnum.ValueA">Value A</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does anyone know if you could do something like `MyEnum: Enum<MyEnum> = MyEnum` to pass the enum *type-safely*?

Comment: @FerranMaylinch I don't think that's necessary as you can just do `MyEnum = MyEnum;` now and it compiles just fine. Must have changed around Angular 8's version of TS.

Comment: `MyEnum: typeof MyEnum = MyEnum;` :)

Comment: Does `typeof MyEnum` makes sense? It returns object. Is it different than set to `any`?

Comment: @JuanIgnacioAvendañoHuergo Actually you can just do `MyEnum = MyEnum`. There isn't much point to typing this beyond that.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using const enum:
`'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment or type query.ts(2475)`

Comment: @JamieBarker fair enough. Not sure if there is a solution when using const enum.