# Angular 5 and Enums at html view from different file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

I was trying to define the enum in another file to use it in other places as well.
For example on html view. Is this possible?

enums.model.ts

```
export enum MyEnum{
    First = 1,
    Second= 2
}
```

my-summary.component.ts

```
import {MyEnum} from "./app/models";
@Component({
    selector: "my-summary",
    templateUrl: "./my-summary.component.html"]
})
export class MySummaryComponent{ }
```

my-summary.component.html

```
   <div>
      {{MyEnum.First}}
   </div>
```

And it doesn't work. Module `'"path/app/models/index"' has no exported member 'MyEnum`'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use enum in Angular 2 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277527/how-to-use-enum-in-angular-2-templates)

Comment: what is in your index.ts file?
If your dont have one then look at  Sachila's answer below..
Path should be: "./app/models/enums.model"

Having said that I've never been able to import a enum in angular 4.

Answer (score 12):

Assign `enum` to a variable inside component.

```
import {MyEnum} from "./app/models";
@Component({
    selector: "my-summary",
    templateUrl: "./my-summary.component.html"]
})
export class MySummaryComponent{
   MyEnum = MyEnum;
 }
```

Comment: Still error `ERROR in path/my-summary.component.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"path/app/models/index"' has no exported member 'MyEnum'.`

Comment: path should be `import {MyEnum} from "./app/models/enums.mode";`

Comment: any other way to achieve this globally? I have "CountryCodes" enum and I need to access it in structural directive that restricts block  in various components by countrycodes and some other input params - so I will need to import this every time I want to use the directive(